# How to open a Qt project?

Tags: qt, qt-creator

I am using qt Creator.

I saved all my projects in a folder in E:/ drive.

I am a beginner. How do I open a project which I created using qt Creator a few weeks back? It does not feature in the recent projects...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> File -> Open File or Project

Navigate to your project file, which is a file with a .pro extension and select that for opening.

Comment: After doing it, and i click on compile and run, it says qtCreator needs a compiler to set up and build

Comment: You need to add a kit to tell Qt Creator what compiler to use and where to save the builds http://qt-project.org/doc/qtcreator-2.6/creator-targets.html

Answer (score 3):

Look for the `.pro` project file consisting of the project information.

Answer (score 0):

Apart from `.pro` files you can also open the project file for the project: `CMakeLists.txt` (CMake), `.pro` (qmake), `.qbs` (Qbs), `meson.build` (Meson), `pyproject` (Python), or `Makefile.am` (Autotools, experimental).